# Dynamic arrays of arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

If I have:

```
typedef char pos[2]; /*btw I now know no one should do this*/

void someFunction(void) {
    pos *s = malloc(sizeof(pos) * 2);
}
```

In the cases like this how s working? What is it? Arrays are like pointers except when you use sizeof on them you will get the "correct" size. So in this case the following means that s is going to be a pointing to a sizeof(char)*4 sized memory? But the type of s is a pointer to a pointer which means that you can't use s as a one dimensional array (or a pointer which points chars ) becouse you "still need to go through one level/layer of indirection/pointer". Or am I wrong?

How can I use s? As a 2 dimensional array or as a one dimensional one?

(If you are interested: I need this bc I want to return two pos from a function. Is there a better way? (despite fixing this and using a struct for storing position data instead of a 2-sized array))

Answer (score 2):

This `typedef` costruct is just equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunction(void) {
    char (*pos)[2];
    pos = malloc(sizeof(*pos) * 2);

    pos[0][0] = 1;
}

int main(void) {
    someFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

That means that `pos` is the pointer to two-elements array of `char`. You can use just like as two-dimensional array with fixed column size as two. Number of rows is controlled by `malloc()` call, in your case it happened to be two as well.